# How to store array data of drag and drop form builder

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I want to know what's the best way to store array data of a dynamic form builder in mysql databse and retieve them based on each value?

Comment: Haven't tried anything. searching for

Comment: you should at least give a sample data and sample expected output you want to store into db

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying your Array is dynamic and you want to store into `MySQL`.

You can define any one column in DB for this purpose. store the the JSON encoded array output via `json_encode()` into that field.

And when you want to retrieve those values, just read and decode it via `json_decode()`

Otherwise there is no sense to create new columns dynamically via code.